# Complications caused by using inline frames

Tags: html, inline, frames, iframe

What are some complications that can be caused by framing a website?

I'm looking to frame a relatively complex website that is based on jspx.

So far I've found that Ajax functions don't work and I've heard that this is because of security issues.

What other things of this nature might go wrong when framing a website?

Thank you very much for any help.

Best,
Peter

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a fairly annoying thing happen with one of my sites being framed (not my decision) where IE was not logging people on. It was only on certain users so my best guess was that IE was doing something strange and (possibly) wrong with the session cookie due to 'security settings'. Needless to say I just implemented a framebreaker to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

- Bookmarking doesn't work properly
- Copying and pasting a URL to email / IM / whatever to a friend sends users to a different view
- Search engines send users to orphan pages